# Не получается вывести строку, оповещающую о победе в игре 'Угадай загаданное число'

Tags: python, for, while

Только начал заниматься изучением питона, это мой первый опыт в изучение ЯП. Взялся написать свой первый мини-мини-мини проект. Суть заключается в игре Угадай число, где компьютер сам, рандомным образом создает число. При этом программа дает подсказки игроку, при неправильном ответе.
Но когда пользователь угадывает число, то программа просто просит выбрать число еще раз!

Вот что получается при выводе. В скобках мои комментарии, чтобы было понятнее

Попробуйте угадать число: 2 (Верный ответ, но программа все равно спрашивает, хотя должна завершить работу)
Попробуйте угадать число: 1(Не верный ответ)
У вас осталось две попытки, а также загаданное число меньше 3!
Попробуйте угадать число:

[image: Вот сам код]

Comment: пожалуйста опубликуйте свой пример обычным текстом.

Comment: так вы в первом условии только проверяете что число не угадано, но не выходите из цикла, если пользователь угадал

Comment: Везде где надо закончить цикл ставьте `break`, где-то стоит, где-то нет

Comment: спасибо большое за ответы, такая глупая ошибка, состоящая из двух пробелов.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас ошибка, заключается в условии: `if user_int != rndm_1:`, когда Вы вводите верное число - это условие становиться True и программа игнорирует все последующее условия. Чтобы это исправить, просто удалите это условие. И ещё хочу дать Вам совет: вместо того чтобы писать:

```js
if rndm_1 < 3:
  if a == 1:
```

Вы можете просто написать: `if rndm_1 < 3 and a == 1:`
Успехов Вам в изучении Python!

Comment: спасибо вам большое, а также, огромное спасибо за наставление!